# Google Calendar API on add event callback for sync

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am using `google-api-php-client`for fetching and inserting Google Calendar events. Now I want to synchronize events on my system with events on Google Calendar.

I am wondering, if I add Event in Google Calendar, can it be automatically added in my system (maybe with some callback url) so I don't need to use CRON jobs to recheck events in Google Calendar in some time interval?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Google provides both iCal and XML output for viewing from external applications.  This URL can be found by clicking on the drop down from your calendar name while logged in, selecting settings, and the calendar name.  The private address row gives you both iCal and XML URLs.

Here are instructions for [Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/See-your-Google-Calendar-in-Outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126) and [iCal](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for answer! After almost 2 years :) This link will not push added event  data to server. Anyway, you need to load data from these URLs time by time - for example with CRON job.